# build python list from ansible list of values

Tags: python, django, ansible

I'm trying to 12-factor my django settings by passing environment variables from ansible. My problem is that I don't know how to pass the variables `host1` and `host2` from an ansible yaml file, so that `MYSETTING` is a python list, not a string.

I'm trying to get:

```
MYSETTING = ['host1', 'host2']   # this should be a list, not a string
```

I have tried various options in ansible, but they both seem to result in `MYSETTING` being a string:

```
# settings.py
MYSETTING = os.environ.get(ANSIBLE_VALUE, [])

# ansible vars file
ANSIBLE_VALUE: "['host1', 'host2']"
```

or

```
# settings.py
MYSETTING = [os.environ.get(ANSIBLE_VALUE, None)]

# ansible vars file
ANSIBLE_VALUE: "'host1', 'host2'"
```

but neither option seems to work. I'm sure there is something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your environment variable is a string type. You can change string into a list with ast library

```
import ast

MYSETTING = ast.literal_eval(os.environ.get(ANSIBLE_VALUE, '[]'))
```

Comment: this is quite cool! I'm hoping to find a solution that relies on a proper ansible syntax, but if there is no such option, I'll go with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
# In settings.py
   ADMINS = ['ws.kwak', 'jm0926.kim', 'viet.long', 'nam.nv12', 'phuong.nv2']
#In other files like views.py
    from django.conf import settings
    settings.ADMINS
```